# What am I missing with this API connection request string?

Tags: api, ticker

I have my api_key in a ".env". I could be overthinking it. Here's my code as it currently stands, works without hiding the api_key. My syntax is incorrect when I pull from process.env.API_KEY.

```
function call_api(finishedAPI, ticker) {
    request('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/' + ticker + '/quote?token= + 'api_key', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}
        if (res.statusCode === 200){
           finishedAPI(body);
        };
    });
};
```

I know there's a simpler way to do this and my research to google cues aren't firing on all cylinders. I'll buy you coffee or a tomato basil panini from Starbucks :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

function call_api(finishedAPI, ticker) {
request('https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/' + ticker + '/quote?token=' + API_KEY, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
if (err) {return console.log(err);}
if (res.statusCode === 200){
finishedAPI(body);
};
});
};

Answer (score 0):

Should be. It also looks like your trying to use a callback incorrectly.

**NOTE** though, it's easy to tell you should always state the lang used. Just makes things easy for everyone.

```
function call_api(ticker, finishedAPI) {
    request({url: 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/' + ticker + '/quote?token= + 'api_key'}, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {return console.log(err);}
        if (res.statusCode === 200){
           finishedAPI(body);
        };
    });
};

function main(){
  call_api(ticker, function(fromCallapi){
     if(fromCallapi) console.log(fromCallapi);
  })
}
```

A callback would be called within another method or operation, and would returned to caller once the operation is completed by, passing the process, variable, or method back to it's caller.

**NOTE** the param `finishedAPI` should be renamed as `callback` it best practice to indicate that the process, variable, or method will be returning the result back to caller. Please note, that overly using callbacks can be overall affect the performance of you application and can hang processes. Hope that helps

***UPDATE***

If you have plan on using `.env` you'll need to use `require('dotenv').config(path: '/path/to/.env')` once loaded for example to access a variable named `VARIBLE_NAME`, you would access the env variable using `process.env.VARIBLE_NAME`

Comment: thank you for your response. I understand how a call back function works. I can't get my mind "unstuck" from the best way to include the api_key once in the .env